# Appending elements to empty list in python

Tags: python, list, function, append

I have two functions shown here. `for_coordinates_outside_nest(tag_coord)` and `defining_polygon_outside_nest(tag_data)`. What i am trying to do here is, if the functions returns True, i would like to append the numbers returned by the function to `ants_inroi_outsidenest`. The code works fine. But when i try to print `ants_inroi_outsidenest`, i am getting :

`this-[971]
this-[971, 977]
this-[971, 977, 728]
this-[971, 977, 728, 740]`

What i want is a single list `this-[971,977,728,740]`. Any suggestions will be heavily appreciated.

```
def for_coordinates_outside_nest(tag_coord):
    poly = [1000,2100,80,1900]  
    bbPath = mplPath.Path(np.array([[poly[0],poly[1]],[poly[3],poly[1]],[poly[3],poly[2]],[poly[0],poly[2]]]))
    if bbPath.contains_point((tag_coord)):
       return True
    else:
       return False

def defining_polygon_outside_nest(tag_data):
    ants_in_arena = []
    ants_inroi_outsidenest = []
    for id, (x,y) in tag_data:
        ants_in_arena.append(id)
        if for_coordinates_outside_nest((x,y)) is True:
            ants_inroi_outsidenest.append(id)
            print "this-" + str(ants_inroi_outsidenest)
    return ants_inroi_outsidenest
```

Comment: Your `print` statement must be indented further than in your code snippet

Comment: @Chris_Rands I tried doing it, it prints the same.

Comment: What I meant is it should be indented (like your original code before editing, which I believe would produce the output you wanted). Just think, you want to `print` at the end of the loop not each iteration

Comment: @Chris_Rands. Hey thank you. It was a stupid mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Actually the list contains the elements you need. It is a 1-dim list with the values you add in the loop.
Your problem is just that the print function is inside the loop. So, every time you add an element to the list it prints the entire list which contains 1 elements in the first loop, 2 elements in the 2nd, ... and so on.
You should do this:

```
def defining_polygon_outside_nest(tag_data):
    ants_in_arena = []
    ants_inroi_outsidenest = []
    for id, (x,y) in tag_data:
        ants_in_arena.append(id)
        if for_coordinates_outside_nest((x,y)) is True:
            ants_inroi_outsidenest.append(id)
    print "this-" + str(ants_inroi_outsidenest)
    return ants_inroi_outsidenest
```